# Colors not consistent in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/secondary_user_title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tweddleimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/secondary_user_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout03"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout02" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/line1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout04"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout03"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Tweddle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/tweddle_status"
                android:paddingLeft="82dp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                android:text="via Mobile"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout06"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout04"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contactus"
            style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_contactus" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/help"
            style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_help" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ext1"
            style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ext2"
            style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Above is my layout's code, but it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mIRT.png).

When in graphical mode, I click that bottom piece, I see: 
@+id/relativelayout01 and Background #000000
Anybody able to spot this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your height is set to wrap content. The bottom background is the default dark background. Change the root tag to use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` if you want the black to fill the whole screen.